# List of ints to list of strings in MATLAB

Tags: string, list, matlab, plot, legend

I have a list of integers

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, ...]
```

And I want to use them as a legend in a plot.  My understanding is that I need to give the command

```
legend('0','10','20','30', ...)
```

So how do I get a list of strings from my original vector to pass to `legend()`?

`num2str` isn't working for me because I get just one long string.  I'm still a little new to MATLAB syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
legend(num2str([0, 10, 20, 30]'))
```

Converting a **column** vector of numbers will produce a char array with m rows, where each row can be a legend entry.

Comment: To further clarify, I wasn't transposing to a column vector and that's why I was getting one big string.